# How to join these tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in a database, as follows:

`users`:

```
  user_id                     name              pbal

    1                          m1               100
    2                          m2               200
    3                          m3               300
    4                          m4               400
    5                          m5               500
```

`payouts`:

```
    id                       user_id           amount

    1                          1                100
    2                          1                200
    3                          2                300
    4                          1                400
```

`blocked`:

```
   id                          user_id           status
 ------                        --------          ------
    1                           2                 block
    2                           3                 block
```

Now I want to make a list that excludes users whose `user_id` is in the `blocked` table, and that calculates a new total amount based on the `pbal` from `users` and the `amount` from the related rows in `payouts`:

```
   name                 total_amount
   -----                ------------
    m1                    800
    m5                    500
    m4                    400
```

I have been trying for half an hour, but failed. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why is `status` stored in a table separate from `users` in the first place?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
SELECT u.name, u.user_id, MAX(u.pbal) + SUM(p.amount) AS total_amount
FROM dbo.Payouts p 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Blocked b ON u.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name
ORDER BY MAX(u.pbal) + SUM(p.amount) DESC;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible answer:

```
SELECT u.name, u.user_id, 
    u.pbal + (
        -- this takes amounts from the payouts table
        SELECT SUM(p.amount) 
        FROM dbo.Payouts p 
        WHERE u.user_id = p.user_id
    ) AS total
FROM dbo.Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- this excludes blocked users
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Blocked b 
    WHERE u.user_id = b.user_id
)
ORDER BY total;
```

I prefer subqueries in this case because they make it a bit more explicit